# awk concatenate next lines when matching

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, awk

I am using awk to analyze a text file and concatenate lines matching a regex with the following line. I am using the following command:

```
awk '/^ [0-9]/{printf $0 ;next;}1' *filename*
```

When I test it from the prompt it works as expected but when I put the same command in a bash script the output is the same as the input file.

Any idea on why this should not work in a bash script?

**UPDATE**

Here's the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

for FILE in $( ls *.raw )
do
    awk '/^ [0-9]/{printf $0 ;next;}1' FILE > temp
done
```

I tried using `awk '/pattern/{printf "%s",$0;next}1' file` as suggested by @Kent but it would just add %s at the beginning of the file.

**SOLVED**

I modified the command to concatenate the matching line with the two following lines using *getline* as follows:

```
(awk '/^ [0-9]/{l1=$0;getline;l2=(l1  $0);getline; print l2 $0}' < input_file) > output_file
```

Comment: better way: `awk '/pattern/{printf "%s",$0;next}1' file` and you have to show your bash code, otherwise nobody can even **guess** what is the problem.

Comment: set -x # to debug and see what does it have while executing.

Comment: `awk '/^ [0-9]/{printf $0 ;next;}1' *filename*` whenever pattern found it prints line without `"\n"` as you are using `printf`, if pattern is not found line will be printed as you have used `1` that is  `}1' *filename*`, As Kent said you should describe your requirement clearly.

Comment: Never use `printf $0` as that will fail cryptically when `$0` contains `printf` formatting chars like `%`. Use `printf "%s", $0` instead as @Kent told you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the command to concatenate the matching line with the two following lines using getline as follows:

```
(awk '/^ [0-9]/{l1=$0;getline;l2=(l1  $0);getline; print l2 $0}' < input_file) > output_file
```